# Including React-Admin In Another Application *without Redux*

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-admin

I'm trying to upgrade React Admin to V3 but I'm facing issues.

I'm including RA in my SPA when the user types the route `myapp/admin`. My app includes a custom route to include the `Admin` component when the route is hit. More or less like so:

```
// in src/App.js
import Admin from "./admin/App";
export default ({ childProps }) =>
  <Switch>
      <Route path="/admin" exact component={Admin} />
  </Switch>;

// in admin/App.js
// various imports
const App = () => (
  <Admin
    loginPage={MyLoginPage}
    authProvider={authProvider}
    dataProvider={dataProvider}
  >
  </Admin>
);
```

This approach was working before upgrading to V3. However now, after upgrading react admin and its dependencies, I hit the following error

```
Error: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(ConnectedRouterWithContext)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(ConnectedRouterWithContext) in connect options.
```

Some more info:

- I suspect that this is either due to a version mismatch or that I
  need to wrap Admin in a Provider. The doc provides more instructions
  on [Including React-Admin In Another Redux Application](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CustomApp.html). However
  my parent app is not using redux nor redux-saga, and I don't have
  much knowledge on these framework now.
- I have followed the [UPGRADE guide](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/UPGRADE.md) but have not found the answer to my problem there yet.
- I believe I have the right versions for my dependencies (most of which I've had to install specifically for the upgrade):

```
    "ra-data-json-server": "^3.0.4",
    "ra-data-simple-rest": "^3.0.3",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.4.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
```

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon the same issue - if question still valid or somebody else is searching for a solution. Upgrading following packages resolved the issue for me:

After upgrading to `react-admin@3.3.0`

Upgraded also to (currenlty) latest

- `redux@4.0.5`
- `react-redux@7.2.0`